# Chown permission denied while Docker volume binding

Tags: linux, docker, chown

I ran this command but container doesn't run:

***docker container run -p 6379:6379 -v /home/user/redis/data:/data redis***

And after checking its logs:

***find: '.' Permission denied***

***chown: changing  ownership of '.' Permission denied.***

Kindly let me know how to resolve this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo chown "$USER":"$USER" /home/"$USER"/.docker -R
sudo chmod g+rwx "$HOME/.docker" -R
```

Comment: Can you please explain your answer? What these commands do?

Comment: `sudo chown "$USER":"$USER" /home/"$USER"/.docker -R`

By this u r making .docker file owner as ur current user

`sudo chmod g+rwx "$HOME/.docker" -R`

By this u r changing file permission as read+write+execute